# JavaMail without SMTP

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, mail-server

I am using Javamail API to send notification mails from my application but , the network administrator gave me mail host as **mail.mycompany.com** , how to use this with in Javamail without specifiying the smtp.

it is like **mail.google.com** instead of **smtp.gmail.com**

so mine should be **smtp.mycompany.com** instead he gave  me **mail.mycompany.com**

what to tell the administrator about this? I also tried to ping smtp.mycompany.com it is not pinging , it says ping request could not find the host. Any idea what is going on ?

Note :  **smtp.mycompany.com** is example address

```
 props.put("mail.smtp.host", "stmp.mycompany.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",              
        "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```

Thanks

Comment: Ask the administrator if this is the name of an SMTP server. If it is - use it, if not - tell him you need an SMTP server.

Comment: An SMTP server can be in an address such as giraffe.zoo.org, it's just a hostname. Web servers can exist in addresses that don't start with www too.

Comment: Ok admin told me , smtp is not active for our mail , should it be activated ? or is there any other way !

Comment: To send out emails you need an SMTP server. At least I am not aware of any other way.

Comment: About the only interesting mail server that might not use SMTP is Microsoft Exchange.  Exchange **can** support SMTP, but the administrator needs to enable it.  If they're not willing to do that, it's much harder to use it with JavaMail.  There are some [JavaMail third party products](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/third-party-136965.html) that support the native Exchange protocols that you might consider.

Comment: @bill I wonder wat oracle doing about  link rots  , the third party products at oracle web site goes to movie download sites and porn :)) check  the third link witnin  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/third-party-136965.html  http://www.exjello.org/

Comment: Ya, sorry, no one is checking these links for validity on a regular basis.  I'll try to clean them up when I get a chance.

Comment: These companies like Oracle they have to introduce new Departments can be called as link rot department basically they check every link they are dead or not and others

Comment: by the i have solved the problem was with I was writing message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(" Notification ")); , instead of message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("notification@mycompany.com")); , but one more question how to make sender name displayed when the mail is sent instead of mail address

Comment: This question is better than your other one, if you've solved your problem completely, then perhaps you can officially answer it below for completeness =] the rules you so hate on this site are what lead to such good quality questions and answers which I'm sure you find very helpful ;P

Answer (score 1):

If `mail.mycompany.com` is an SMTP server you should still use it for SMTP.
The name is not important here but the service which is provided by this server.